# removing array of GKGridGraphNodes from GKGridGraph unexpectedly slow

Tags: swift, path-finding, gamekit

I am creating a 150 x 150 `GKGridGraph` for the purposes of A* pathfinding.

```
var graph = GKGridGraph(fromGridStartingAt: int2(0, 0), width: 150, height: 150, diagonalsAllowed: true)
```

I'm then looping through pixels of a reference map image and adding nodes to an array to be removed from the graph.

```
func getWalls(navMap: [bool], width: Int, height: Int) -> [GKGridGraphNode] {
     var walls = [GKGridGraphNode]()
     for(index, value) in navMap.enumberated() {
         if(!value) { continue }
         let x = index % width
         let y = index / width
         if let node = graph.node(atGridPosition: vector_int2(Int32(x),Int32(y))) {
                 walls.append(node)
         }
     }

     return walls
}
```

up to this point everything is performant, but as soon as I attempt to remove the walls from the graph my program hangs for a LONG time.

```
 graph?.remove(walls)
```

The thing that surprises me is that once the graph is setup, A* pathfinding on the grid runs super fast. While I expected pathfinding might be slow on such a large grid, I'm surprised that simply deleting a large chunk of nodes would cause such a significant performance hit.

**So my question is WHY would removing a collection of nodes from GKGridGraph cause such a slowdown, and is there a more performant way to implement this operation?**

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.